# Cannot Use RCP in Windows Server 2008, But OK with RSH, Why?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rcp, rsh

I am trying to use "rcp" command to copy files from a Unix computer to a Windows Server 2008 R2 computer.  Somehow, it fails to copy anything.

For example, I am using the following command to copy the .rhosts file from the Unix computer to the Windows computer:

```
C:\Windows\posix.exe /u /c /bin/rcp <IP-address>.<user>:/u/<user>/.rhosts  \temp.
```

There is no error message. The only thing that I can tell it has failed is the simple fact that the files haven't been copied from Unix.

I don't have any problem running "rsh" command in the same Windows computer.  I would think that they should both work or they should both fail.  I didn't expect to see one works but the other fails. Moreover, I have no problem running both "rsh" and "rcp" in a Windows Server 2003 R2 computer.  Therefore, I know that the Unix side is OK.  There must be something wrong in the Windows side.

I have checked the EventViewer, and there is no error message.

I have run "Process Monitor" in Windows Server 2008 R2 to check the events from running both "rsh" and "rcp" commands.  I cannot find anything unusual.  Actually the recorded events from both "rsh" and "rcp" look almost the same (of course the process-IDs are different).

I have also tried this in a Windows Server 2008 (not R2) computer. But the result is the same as the Windows Server 2008 R2 - "rsh" works, "rcp" fails.

Can someone help me with this?  Thanks in advance.

Jay Chan

Comment: According to this web page, someone else had the same problem: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=728022.  Somehow, rsh works as long as rlogin service is running.  But in order to have rcp also works, we need to have rsh service running.  This is kind of confusing.  I figure the rsh service that he was referring to is a Windows service.  But I cannot find it in the Windows Server 2008 R2 server.  I cannot find it in the Windows 2003 server that has both rsh and rcp working.  Any one knows the answer?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I end up solving this problem by using PSCP instead of RCP. I download PSCP from this web address: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html. I believe the problem may have to do with the security in Windows Server 2008 is stronger than previous versions, and it doesn't allow the kind of way of validating a user credential that RCP uses, or something like that. PSCP requires explicitly passing the user name and password, and Windows Server 2008 like that.